# Sinatra app executes during load instead of after run method issued

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, thin

This is a stripped down example of a real app I am building.  When I execute my app, this is the result I get.  You'll notice that it says that it is running before it is starting.  You'll also notice it never says running after the start is issued.

```
bundle exec rackup
Using thin;
Sapp::App running.
Starting Sapp::App
== Sinatra (v1.4.7) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.7.0 codename Dunder Mifflin)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop
```

My config.ru is:

```
# http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/webmachine/Webmachine/Adapters/Rack
$started = false
require 'thin'
require 'sinatra'
set :server, (ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'production' || ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'staging' ? 'rack' : 'thin')
puts "Using #{settings.server};"
load 'webmachine/adapters/rack.rb'
load File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'sapp.rb')
$started = true
puts 'Starting Sapp::App'
#Sapp::App.run!
Sinatra::Application.run!
```

I am setting $started just to try to fix this problem, but it doesn't help.  My app is executed before it is set.  I could control that but, and this is the rub, **it does not execute after the run is issued.**

sapp.rb is:

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] ||= 'development'
Bundler.setup
$: << File.expand_path('../', __FILE__)
$: << File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load(
    File.expand_path("../.env.#{ENV['RACK_ENV']}", __FILE__),
    File.expand_path("../.env", __FILE__))
module Sapp
  class App < Sinatra::Application
    puts 'Sapp::App has been started.' if $started
    puts 'Sapp::App running.'

  end
end
```

In the end, if nothing else, Once it says "Starting Sapp::App", it should also say "Sapp::App has been started." and "Sapp::App running."

For the record, both these options do the same thing:

```
Sapp::App.run!
Sinatra::Application.run!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I get it.  I put the code in a class, but not it a method. Load or require both run open code like this.  I need to wrap it in methods, and execute the methods, to do what I want to do.

Sinatra examples, which I followed, don't make this clear and simply avoid the topic.  Many are so simple it doesn't make a difference, and some are just coded within the config.ru.  I am coming from Rails and, while I knew this from Rails, it didn't make much of a difference since the vast majority of the code already exists in methods.

Comment: Also, note that you're subclassing `Sinatra::Application` rather than `Sinatra::Base` which is what needs to be used for [modular style applications](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Modular%20vs.%20Classic%20Style). Can you point me to the Sinatra examples you mention in your answer? If they are part of official documentation, I will fix them.

Comment: @Kashyap Currently reading Sinatra Up and Running to get clear on all of that.  I think it will help.  The app was generated as a modular app using Trevi, but I've modified/played with it heavily trying to include classic examples.  So, it's my inexperience I'd expect.  Thanks.